# Out argument doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, pointers, arguments

I'm parsing a text file - I am able to open it, read it and delete unnecessary pieces from string.
However, I'm not able to get this code to work:

```
size_t read_lines(const char *file_name, char **buffer) {
    size_t n_lines = 0;

    FILE *file = open_file(file_name);

    while (1) {
        char *ln = _read_line(file);

        if (ln == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        n_lines++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    file = open_file(file_name);

    buffer = calloc(n_lines, sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < n_lines; i++) {
        buffer[i] = read_line(file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return n_lines;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char **lines;

    size_t length = read_lines("/Users/honzik/Documents/Xcode/BoioVM/BoioVM/test_file.bic", lines);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
    }

    free(lines);

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is probably crappy code, but it just *should* work.
Or maybe not? The `lines` are equal to `NULL`, but how to get the pointer updated by the function?

*P.S.: Don't worry about all those functions (`open_file`, `read_line`, `_read_line`, ...) they work :)*

Comment: Can we see `_read_line()`?

Comment: You have written three functions named: `read_lines`, `_read_line` and `read_line`. Why?

Comment: Yes that pretty dangerous as it might lead to confusion. It's confusing. Better if you give them more *explicit* names. Like `read_line_with_something()` or something like that.

Comment: Worry about memory leakage or misuse in the `read_lines()` function.  Either you're leaking all the lines returned by `_read_line()` while you're finding out how many lines are in the file, or you are not making separate copies of each line in the second loop, so the array will end up holding multiple copies of the last line.  Neither is likely to be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `read_line()` works as expected, what you want to achieve is only possible with a three star pointer, IMHO this is one case where you can use it because it's not really a three star pointer, it's a two star pointer whose address was passed to a function.

The double `char` pointer in the `read_lines()` function is a local variable to the function, so storing the address returned by `calloc()` in it will not be preserved when the function returns, instead you should pass the address of the pointer and store the return value of `calloc()` by dereferencing the pointer and assigning it to the real two star pointer defined in `main()`, somethin like this

```
size_t read_lines(const char *file_name, char ***buffer)
{
    size_t n_lines = 0;
    FILE *file = open_file(file_name);
    // FIXME: check if `file != NULL' before reading
    while (1) {
        char *ln = _read_line(file);
        if (ln == NULL)
            break;
        n_lines++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    file = open_file(file_name);
    // FIXME: check if `file != NULL' before reading
    *buffer = malloc(n_lines * sizeof(**buffer));
    // FIXME: check that `malloc' did not return `NULL'
    for (int i = 0; i < n_lines; i++)
        (*buffer)[i] = read_line(file);
    fclose(file);
    return n_lines;
}
```

Note that:

1. I replaced `calloc()` with `malloc()` since the line should be `null` terminated inside `read_line()`. Using `calloc()` in this case can hide some bugs that would be very hard to debug. If you instead use `malloc()` you can easily reveal the potential bugs with a tool like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).
2. I added smoe comments to let you see that your code is very unsafe.

On `main()` you would do this

```
#define PLEASE_AVOID_SUCH_LONG_LINES "/Users/honzik/Documents/Xcode/BoioVM/BoioVM/test_file.bic"

size_t length = read_lines(PLEASE_AVOID_SUCH_LONG_LINES, &lines);
/* long lines make the code hard to read even on modern editors */
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked - but it is not unsafe, since the `open_file` functions checks if `fopen` returns `NULL`. If so, it `exit(1)`s.

Comment: You should not handle errors in a convoluted way, and you certainly SHOULD not `exit(1)` on any error. Make your function reusable, do not exit the whole program from it. Just return something that lets the caller know there is an error. Like `NULL`, why do you think `malloc()` returns `NULL` instead of simple calling `exit(0)`.

Comment: Well, returning `NULL` leads to `if (result == NULL)` everywhere. I would probably never use `open_file` anywhere else, and returning `NULL` from it would cause just a general failure of the whole program, so I will have to `exit(1)` somewhere else. And my code isn't meant to be reused by someone. If so, he must deal with this fact.